# Want to Disable two week days instead of Sunday and Saturday

Tags: jquery, datepicker, pikaday

```
<input id="datepicker">

    var picker = new Pikaday({
    disableDayFn: function(date){
        // Disable Monday
        return date.getDay() === 1;
    },
    field: document.getElementById('datepicker')
});
```

Currently above code is disabling one day, I want it to disable two days. please help me out to sort it

Example : JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jpwk4wpv/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jpwk4wpv/82/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `||`(OR) operation inside `disableDayFn` as shown :-

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    disableDayFn: function(date){
        // Disable Monday and Tuesday
        return (date.getDay() === 1 || date.getDay() === 2);
    },
    field: document.getElementById('datepicker')
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jpwk4wpv/82/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable two days using || like this:

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
disableDayFn: function(date){
    // Disable Monday
    return date.getDay() === 1 || date.getDay() === 2;
},
field: document.getElementById('datepicker')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or... pass in an array with disabled days

```
// disabled days array
var disabledDays = [1,2]

//your disabledDayFn
disableDayFn: function(date){
    return disabledDays.includes(date.getDay)
}
```